# Create a two dimensional array in a stored procedure in SQL Server in CSV format

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, csv

I know that array formats do not exist in stored procedure let alone 2-D array. But I use CSV string to store the values of the array using comma delimiter. My main question is can I store in the same way the values which I need in a 2-D format with the help of another delimiter. If yes, Can anyone guide me in the right way to do that?

The table I have is something like this....

```
    UserID    |   ItemID
  ---------------------------
    User1         1 
    User1         2 
    User2         3 
    User2         1
```

What I need is create a two dimensional result where for each item I store the users who requested it. So I want to create a csv string like this....

```
   "1:User1,User2,2:User1,3:User2"
```

Something similar to the format is it possible, to create this in stored procedure and split the string into 2-d array in c#.

Comment: Don't go there. Use a table to implement array like structure, or 2 tables with a relationship of 1 to many to implement a jagged array like structure. Keeping a delimited string in a database table should be avoided in almost any situation (in my 16 years of programming, only once I've chosen to store values as a delimited string in the database, and that's only because I've used them as delimited strings outside of the database).

Comment: I am not trying to store the string in the database. I just need to create a string like this in the stored procedure and pass it to my c# code where I can interpret as 2-d array.How to do that??

Comment: Don't go there either. use a select statement to fill a DataTable and convert it to a two dimensional array in you c# code. Doing this kind of thing in c# is much easier and will work mach faster then doing it in t-sql.

Answer (score 1):

The 2D Array you describe would be nice if you need to access both ways, but bear in mind it will probably be very sparse and waste a lot of memory.

If you want to use the data you describe in C#, I would look at  [Linq GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq) first. You can easily project the data into a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` that holds all the items id's per Userid.

Comment: Actually thank you for pointing me in the right direction I think this will suit my needs but can you show me a sample of how to do that or an article on how to do it step by step since I am new to Linq concept and even after spending hours to try to figure it out, I still can't understand how to implement a Linq query and how to store the results I need in IEnumerable. And since I am using ADO.NET Entity Model do i need to create to classes like mentioned in the post you linked. Truly I am clueless on whats happening please help me out.

Comment: Hi Amalpriya, I'd love to help you but at the moment I'm quite busy so not going be able to any time soon sorry. Good luck, GJ